# How to automate a JavaScript/html traffic light sequence using setinterval?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and i am tying to automate this traffic light sequence. I have used if and if else statements to preform the task but I am unable to automate it so it will continually run after one click of the button :

```
function changelight(){

    if (current==colours[0]){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = colours[0];
        ctx.fill();


        var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx1.stroke();
        ctx1.fillStyle = colours[1];
        ctx1.fill();


        var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx2.stroke();
        ctx2.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx2.fill();
        current=colours[4];  
    }

    else if (current==colours[4]){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx.fill();


        var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx1.stroke();
        ctx1.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx1.fill();


        var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx2.stroke();
        ctx2.fillStyle = colours[2];
        ctx2.fill();
        current=colours[2];  
    }

    else if (current==colours[2]){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx.fill();


        var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx1.stroke();
        ctx1.fillStyle = colours[1];
        ctx1.fill();


        var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx2.stroke();
        ctx2.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx2.fill();
        current=colours[1];  
    }

    else if (current==colours[1]){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = colours[0];
        ctx.fill();


        var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx1.stroke();
        ctx1.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx1.fill();


        var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
        ctx2.stroke();
        ctx2.fillStyle = colours[3];
        ctx2.fill();
        current=colours[0];  
    }



    }
    </script>


        <br><br>
        <button onclick="changelight()">Click</button>
```

I know I need to do it with setInterval but I have no idea how to do it. All my previous attempts have failed please help.

Comment: Uh... `setInterval(changelight, 1000);`?

Comment: Quite aside from the code needing a LOT of cleanup (just put `var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas'), ctx = c.getContext('2d');` at the start of the function, and use that one variable instead of getting the same canvas and the same context repeatedly... to name one issue) the logic could use some work, and it may be a good idea to name your colours, eg. `colours = {red: "#ff0000", yellow: "#ffff00", green: "#00ff00", off: "#000000"};`

Comment: Also, what the heck is `10,12*Math.PI` for? Just `0,Math.PI*2` will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clean things up a bit... you can move all the drawing to one place.  Then use a start and stop function.  Actually, you can easily combine the start and stop but I will leave that to you.  Here you go:

```js
function light(c) {
  this.current = 0;
  this.colors = ["green", "yellow", "red"];
  this.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
}

light.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  this.ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 12 * Math.PI);
  this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[this.current];
  this.ctx.fill();
}

light.prototype.start = function() {
  if(this.interval)
    return;
  this.draw();
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    this.current = (this.current + 1) % this.colors.length;
    console.log("drawing: ", this.colors[this.current]);
    this.draw();
  }.bind(this), 3000);
}

light.prototype.stop = function() {
  if (!this.interval)
    return;
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  delete this.interval;
}

var myLight = new light(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<button onclick="myLight.start()">start</button>
<button onclick="myLight.stop()">stop</button>
```

Comment: The closure function of `setInterval()` could be extracted to a separate `light.prototype.animate` function - besides that: good refactoring

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually write ready-to-go code, but there are so many things wrong with yours that I was... compelled to.

Functions: use 'em! Don't copy-paste the same code over and over, that's a sign you're doing it wrong!

`setInterval` takes a reference to a function. I don't know what your "previous attempts" were since you never bothered telling us, but I'll hazard a guess that you wrote `setInterval(changelight(), 1000)` and wondered why it only ever did the first one.

You can re-use a canvas context! Just get it once and draw on it forever!

Avoid "magic numbers" like these `colours[0]` in your original code. Give things meaningful names, such as `colours.red`, `colours.off` so you can easily find and change them if you want!

Use a counter to step through your cycles, don't rely on equality to some arbitrary value. Use `%` operator to effectively create a repeating cycle of the given length.

Find patterns and exploit them. A UK traffic light goes in four steps: (red), (red+yellow), (green), (red). US is similar but without the (red+yellow) step... I guess they like testing people's reflexes or something.

Put it all together, this is what you get:

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.width = 150;
c.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(c);

var cycle = 0,
    colours = {
      red: "#cc0000",
      yellow: "#cccc00",
      green: "#00cc00",
      off: "#333333"
    };

function drawLight(id,colour) {
  // avoid repetition, use a function!
  ctx.fillStyle = colours[colour];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95, 50 + 100*id, 40, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function changelight(){
  ctx.stokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  
  // top light: red if cycle = 0 or 1, off otherwise
  drawLight(0, cycle <= 1 ? 'red' : 'off');
  
  // middle light: yellow if cycle = 3 (and 1 for UK lights, we have red+yellow before green), off otherwise
  drawLight(1, cycle == 1 || cycle == 3 ? 'yellow' : 'off');
  
  // bottom light: green if cycle = 2
  drawLight(2, cycle == 2 ? 'green' : 'off');
  
  // increment cycle
  cycle = (cycle + 1) % 4;
}

// start the magic
setInterval(changelight,1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, I would be lost without this